# What is wrong with this str_replace?

Tags: php, str-replace

```
<?php
$date = date('n/j/Y');
$lines = file('../lines.txt');

foreach($lines as $line)

$line = str_replace($date, '', $line);

echo $line;
?>
```

Why will the above str_replace work for me, no matter how I re-arrange it I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in File line 20 ($line = str_replace ....)

Comment: shouldn't you print_r or var_dump `$lines`. `$line` was what foreach assigned assigned on each iteration of `$lines`

Comment: The code as you provided it cannot cause the error from the question. You must have oversimplified it so that it syntactically correct at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

- Probably you forgot to close one of the previous strings.
- str_replace accepts arrays as third argument => you don't need the foreach. str_replace can process the whole $lines in one step.